# Linux Makefile: Why include/config/%.conf always got built?

Tags: linux, makefile

I am using Linux Makefile(4.2.0).

If i invoke make with a non-exist target, for example, "make ABCDEF", make always remake target: **include/config/%.conf** (near line 570), whose recipe is "**make silentoldconfig**".

Below is the target (near line 556):

```
# Read in config
-include include/config/auto.conf

ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)
# Read in dependencies to all Kconfig* files, make sure to run
# oldconfig if changes are detected.
-include include/config/auto.conf.cmd

# To avoid any implicit rule to kick in, define an empty command
$(KCONFIG_CONFIG) include/config/auto.conf.cmd: ;

# If .config is newer than include/config/auto.conf, someone tinkered
# with it and forgot to run make oldconfig.
# if auto.conf.cmd is missing then we are probably in a cleaned tree so
# we execute the config step to be sure to catch updated Kconfig files
include/config/%.conf: $(KCONFIG_CONFIG) include/config/auto.conf.cmd
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/Makefile silentoldconfig
```

I just wondering why this target "**include/config/%.conf**" always got built? Even the target is not called.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Show the relevant makefile line in its entirety?

Comment: And which file is it generating in that target? Because whichever file that is either doesn't exist or is continually older than its prerequisites. You can see what make thinks is happening with `make -d`.

Comment: But i am not even make this target, why this target build automatically? Yes, i have tried `make -d`, the output says: **Found an implicit rule for `include/config/auto.conf'**

Comment: It should say more than that. It should say which prerequisite of that file it believes is newer and is triggering the build or if that file doesn't exist and it is trying to build it (in which case it should get built I would imagine and not do it again). The answer to "why" is probably because there is an `include` directive for that config file somewhere.

Comment: Sorry i omitted the `-include include/config/auto.conf` line! I just go back to read GNU make manual about how `include` works and how Makefiles are remade, now i know `why`. Thank you, @EtanReisner!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is likely a valid topic the answer is instance specific and (now) contained within the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use make -d to see why a rule is executed